# String.Format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

In C# whenever I wanted to print two digit numbers I've used

```
int digit=1;
Console.Write(digit.ToString("00"));
```

How can I do the same action in Javascript ?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

c# `digit.toString("00")` appends one zero to the left of `digit` (left padding). In javascript I use this functon for that:

```
function zeroPad(nr,base){
  var  len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
  return len > 0? new Array(len).join('0')+nr : nr;
}
zeroPad(1,10);   //=> 01
zeroPad(1,100);  //=> 001
zeroPad(1,1000); //=> 0001
```

You can also rewrite it as an extention to Number:

```
Number.prototype.zeroPad = Number.prototype.zeroPad || 
     function(base){
       var nr = this, len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length)+1;
       return len > 0? new Array(len).join('0')+nr : nr;
    };
 //usage:
(1).zeroPad(10);   //=> 01
(1).zeroPad(100);  //=> 001
(1).zeroPad(1000); //=> 0001
```

[**edit oct. 2021**]

A static es20xx `Number` method, also suitable for negative numbers.

```js
Number.padLeft = (nr, len = 2, padChr = `0`) => 
  `${nr < 0 ? `-` : ``}${`${Math.abs(nr)}`.padStart(len, padChr)}`;
console.log(Number.padLeft(3));
console.log(Number.padLeft(284, 5));
console.log(Number.padLeft(-32, 12));
console.log(Number.padLeft(-0)); // Note: -0 is not < 0
```

Comment: It should be noted that this won't work with negative numbers, i.e. it's made to work with positive numbers only. (Only saying this because I was looking for a similar formatter that deals with neg numbers as well.)

Comment: I would like to point out that, 8 years later, this is what `padStart` does, which major browsers support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 2):

I usually just do something like
`("00000000"+nr).slice(-base)` where `nr` is the number and `base` is the number of digits you want to end up with.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to download [sprintf for javascript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) and writing something like this:

```
int i = 1;
string s = sprintf("%02d", i);
document.write(s); // Prints "01"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var num =10
document.write(num);
```

But if your question is to use two digit numbers twice then you can use this

```
var num1 = 10;
var num2 = 20;
var resultStr = string.concat(num1,num2);
document.write(resultStr);
...
Result: 1020
```

if you want a space in between,

```
var resultStr = string.concat(num1,"",num2);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think was op wants is padding the number if it's < 10, so 1 becomes string 01 or 001

Comment: This wont help, as it doesn't address the problem of String formatting. (e.g. the op wants to have something like `i=1 ==> "01"`)

Comment: Nope, you didn't understand. Your answer has nothing to do with string padding

Comment: @codemonkey: before your first comment came, I was actually modifying the code so couldn't look at it and after saving, the page updated with your comment. So it's not that I have not understood. I have understood it properly. Thanks anyways....

Comment: You still haven't understood it. Your answer still has nothing to do with STRING PADDING. Op was looking for a way to fill out a string with zeros to ensure a fixed length. For instance, 1 becomes "001"