# Adding "0" if clock have one digit

Tags: javascript, clock

i have some clock script. Everything is fine and it's work perfectly but... i have one problem. If at the clock is set one digit hour or minute like 1:5 clock not adding "0" digit before. This what i'v done but it does't work. Can u help me, much thx?

```
window.setInterval(function update_clock() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    $.ajax({
        success: function (clock) {
            document.getElementById("hour").firstChild.nodeValue = currentHours;
            document.getElementById("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = currentMinutes;
            if (currentMinutes.length == 1) {
                currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
            }
        }
    });
}, 999);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.Format in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220693/string-format-in-javascript)

Comment: The "problem" with this code is that `number.length` (e.g. `(42).length`) is *always* `undefined`.

Comment: the names of this topics have nothing in common with my problem...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`currentMinutes` is a number, so it does not have the `length` property. Also, you must check the `length` before set the `currentMinutes` to the `minutes` element.

Something like:

```
var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

$.ajax({
    success: function (clock) {
        if (currentMinutes.toString().length == 1) {
            currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
        }

        document.getElementById("hour").firstChild.nodeValue = currentHours;
        document.getElementById("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = currentMinutes;
    }
});
```

Comment: Rather than checking the string length it's probably easier to just do 
`currentMinutes < 10`

Answer (score 60):

You may use `.slice` to extract a portion of a string. Pass a negative number to it, in order to slice from the end of the string.

Therefore, the following is possible, and quite simple:

```
('0'+currentMinutes).slice(-2)
```

Concatenating with `'0'` makes sure that the target of the operation will always be a string. `('0'+currentMinutes)` will yield a 2 or 3 letter string ("07" or "017", for instance). Slicing the last two characters off that string will give you a 0-padded two-digit number.

Note that the above would yield "00" if `currentMinutes` is `100`, so it assumes that you know the values you'll be working with.

This could be extracted to something more reusable:

```
Number.prototype.zeroPad = function() {
   return ('0'+this).slice(-2);
};
```

That would allow you to write:

```
currentMinutes.zeroPad();
```

You could also make the length of the padding variable:

```
Number.prototype.zeroPad = function(length) {
   length = length || 2; // defaults to 2 if no parameter is passed
   return (new Array(length).join('0')+this).slice(length*-1);
};
```

Which could be called as:

```
currentMinutes.zeroPad(); // e.g. "07" or "17"
currentMinutes.zeroPad(3); // e.g. "007" or "017"
```

Note that while `currentMinutes.zeroPad()` will work, `7.zeroPad()` would not.

Comment: Genious pieces of code like this are why I use S/O. Simple, to the point and why on earth didn't I ever think of this?!

Answer (score 16):

Try using the `padStart()` method. Based on MDN docs, the `padStart()` method keeps padding the string with another string until it reaches the desired length. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to MDN docs on padStart().

If you want to format your string to have 4 digits with leading zeros if less than 4 digits are available. The `padStart()` method can come to the rescue as follows:

```js
let str = "34"

str = str.padStart(4, "0") // results in "0034"
console.log(str)
```

An example of the date case:

```js
var now = new Date(); 
var year= now.getFullYear(); 
var month= (now.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
var day= now.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
var hour = now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
var minute = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML =`${day}-${month}-${year}-${hour}:${minute}`;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

`currentMinutes` won't have a `length` property, as it's a `Number`, not a `String`.

You could force it to be a `String`.

```
if ((currentMinutes+'').length == 1) {
     currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
}
```

**But**, because you have a `Number`, you should make your condition...

```
if (currentMinutes < 10) {
     currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
}
```

If you were especially crazy, you could do...

```
var hoursMinutes = ((new Date)+"").match(/\d+:\d+(?=:)/)[0].split(":");
```

Comment: or just `if (currentMinutes < 10) {`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other awnsers, I created this lines of code:

```js
var now = new Date(); 
var dd = now.getDate(); 
var mm = now.getMonth()+1;
var y = now.getFullYear(); 
var h = now.getHours();
var m = now.getMinutes();

function aZero(n) {
  return n.toString().length == 1 ?  n = '0' + n: n;
}

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML =
  aZero(dd) + "-" +
            aZero(mm) + "-" +
            y +  "   -  "   +
            aZero(h)  + ":" +
            aZero(m);
```

```html
<div id="out">my time :D</div>
```

Cu next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check [sprintf()](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) for javascript.

You could go with something as simple as:

```
sprintf("%02d:%02d", currentHours, currentMinutes);
```

Using functions that accept formatting lets you have much more control over your output, when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

in android(build in)

```
String time=String.format("%02d:%02d",hourOfDay,minute);
```

in javascript use (sprintf.js)

```
int i = 1;
string s = sprintf("%02d", i);
document.write(s); // Prints "01"
```

sprintf.js:
http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Comment: OP needs solution for **JavaScript**, not Android

Answer (score 1):

Try use `('0' + currentTime.getHours()).slice(-2)`

Updated your Question -

```
window.setInterval(function update_clock() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHours = ('0' + currentTime.getHours()).slice(-2);
    var currentMinutes = ('0' + currentTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    $.ajax({
        success: function (clock) {
            document.getElementById("hour").firstChild.nodeValue = currentHours;
            document.getElementById("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = currentMinutes;
            if (currentMinutes.length == 1) {
                currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
            }
        }
    });
}, 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do based on length.

My solution will be

```
  var mnt = '' + (seconds / 60).toFixed();
  if (mnt.toString().length == 1) mnt = '0' + mnt;
  var sec = '' + (seconds % 60).toFixed();
  if (sec.toString().length == 1) sec = '0' + sec;
  return `${mnt}:${sec}`;
```